# How can I use React Testing Library to simulate clicking on Material UI RadioGroup option?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

How can I write a react testing library test script to validate clicking on a Material UI radio button?  The below is a recreation of the issue I am having.

```
import React from 'react';
import Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio';
import RadioGroup from '@material-ui/core/RadioGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel';

export default function RadioButtonsGroup() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('female');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset">
      <FormLabel component="legend">Gender</FormLabel>
      <RadioGroup aria-label="gender" name="gender1" value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
        <FormControlLabel value="female" control={<Radio />} label="Female" />
        <FormControlLabel value="male" control={<Radio />} label="Male" />
        <FormControlLabel value="other" control={<Radio />} label="Other" />
        <FormControlLabel value="disabled" disabled control={<Radio />} label="(Disabled option)" />
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

and the test

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import RadioButtonsGroup from "./demo";

test("can click Male radio option", () => {
  render(<RadioButtonsGroup />);
  const maleLabel = screen.getByLabelText(/Male/);
  fireEvent.click(maleLabel);
  expect(maleLabel).toBeChecked();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey – get by role should help you here. Try:

```
const button = screen.getByRole("radio", { name: "Male" });
```

This should give you access to the radio button with the label as Male.

Then you can do

```
 const leftClick = { button: 0 };

 userEvent.click(button, leftClick);

 expect(button.checked).toBe(true);
```

One thing I've found though is that the `.checked` property doesn't play nice with Typescript so if you're writing typescript, you may get warnings about `.checked` being non-existent

Comment: Sure thing! Glad it helped

Comment: @DamilareOlusakin screen.getByRole("radio", { name: "Male" });
it should be 'name' or 'value' ?